# Replacing old Ramadan days

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sawm, ramadan

Salam brother or sister

I was going to ask you some questions about masturbation during ramadan, you see last year I miss 10 days due to my addiction to masturbation and I thought it was ok until now however I was only able to replace one of the days. So what does that mean should I pay fidya or should I fast 60 days straight fortunately I don't think I can pay fidya because I don't think there is a way for me to pay it what should I do???, however this year was a change I was only able to masturbate twice and insh Allah that my addiction to masturbation will stop once and for all by the end of this year or possible by the end of the month. Please help me.

I didn't know masturbation was haram, And I know I have committed a big sin but is it a necessity to replace considered that 2 years ago or 3 I just hit puberty. In addition is their an easier way if I have to replace it? and does it have to involve with money?

Answer (score 1):

If you missed your days before you hit puberty, inshAllah that does not count against you.
However, if I were you, I would still try to make up those days. If you can't pay the fidya because you don't have the money, then the bare minimum you should do is to fast those days. Even if they are a long time ago.
Maybe in the future you might want to donate or pay that fidya if you can and ask Allah for forgiveness.

Comment: Welcome of [islam.se]. Please add some details on the source of this.

Answer (score 0):

You missed those say purposly and also for something haram which is even worse. I understand you didn't know it was haram at the time but I am sure you knew you are not allowed to miss a day of ramadhan without fasting unless you are seriously ill,the doctor has told you not to fast, you are a pregnant woman and some other reasons.

For each day you have missed you have to fast 60days (I'm notsure if this has to be back to back days).

I would recoment make tauba and fast those day as you will be benefited greatly and your sins will be forgiven InshaAllah

Comment: Please consider providing evidences for your claims!